# Remove line break from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea like this:

`<textarea tabindex="1" maxlength='2000' id="area"></textarea>`

I watch this textarea with jquery:

```
$("#area").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    var msg = $("#area").val().replace("\n", "");
    if (!util.isBlank(msg))
    {
        send(msg);
        $("#area").val("");
    }
});
```

send() submits the message to the server if the return key was pressed and if the message is not blank or only containing line spaces.

The problem: After sending the message, the textarea is not cleared.
On the first page load, the textarea is empty. Once a message was submitted, there is one blank line in the textarea and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem is that the Enter keypress is not being suppressed and is doing its usual browser behaviour (i.e. adding a line break). Add `return false` to the end of your keypress handler to prevent this.

```
$("#area").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    var msg = $("#area").val().replace(/\n/g, "");
    if (!util.isBlank(msg))
    {
        send(msg);
        $("#area").val("");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: replace should be `replace(/\n/g, "");` replace("\n", "") will only delete the first new line

Comment: @Orlando: That line of code came straight from the question so it's possible that's replacing just the first line break is what the OP intended, but I agree it's unlikely.

Comment: To be consistent with all the line breaks, `/(\r?\n|\r\n?)/` is best.

Comment: @AnirudhBalaji: jQuery's `val()` method normalizes line breaks to `\n`.

Answer (score 12):

Thomas, the e.preventDefault(); would need to be wrapped inside a conditional applying it only to the enter key.

```
// Restrict ENTER.
if (e.keyCode == '13') { e.preventDefault(); }
```

The whole function would look something like this (with commenting):

```
// Key Press Listener Attachment for #area.
$("#area").keypress( function (event) {

    // If the key code is not associated with the ENTER key...
    if (event.keyCode != 13) {

        // ...exit the function.
        return false;

    } else {

        // Otherwise prevent the default event.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get the message value, stripping any newline characters.
        var msg = $("#area").val().replace("\n", "");

        // If the message is not blank now...
        if (!util.isBlank(msg)) {

            // ...send the message.
            send(msg);

            // Clear the text area.
            $("#area").val("");

        }

    }

} );
```

Comment: Just for a bit of elegance, I would think that you'd simply check `if (event.keyCode == 13) { // do something; }` and save yourself the extra 3-lines where you return false if keyCode is not equal to 13.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the event.preventDefault() function to prevent the default event action from happening, in this case adding the enter character:

```
$("#area").keypress(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    var msg = $("#area").val().replace("\n", "");
    if (!util.isBlank(msg))
    {
        send(msg);
        $("#area").val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work. As you can imagine, the textarea is meant for text input. If I prevent the default action, then I am not able to enter anything.