# Disable linebreaks in HTML textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, newline

with CSS or any other way, is it possible to disallow newlines in a HTML textarea? So basically I want nothing to happen when the user presses "enter".

Comment: Possible with javascript, but circumventable.  I would just strip them on the server side after submission.

Comment: Do you want the content to visually wrap still? or will `<input type="text".../>` suffice?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#t_area").keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == '13') {
      return false;
    }
  });
});

<textarea id="t_area"></textarea>
```

I would also strip out any newlines using PHP or ASP or whatever server-side scripting language you have access to as well to be completely thorough.

Comment: What happens if the user copies and pastes or drag and drops text that has line breaks into the text area? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429757/remove-line-break-from-textarea/4429785#4429785

Comment: @Clark The same thing that happens if you copy and paste or drag and drop text into a comment box on Stack Overflow. :) It's not full-proof by any means, which is why I highly recommend stripping newlines out with a server-side scripting language as a fail-safe.

Comment: And this could be rather frustrating for the user as well.  Obviously it depends on the situation, but I'd strip it out with php, or javascript - onblur, or sending via ajax, or whenever: txtval = txtval.replace(/\n|\r/ig, '');

Comment: Well, disabling \n is not the same as stripping \n. For my case I need to preserve \n, I just don't want to wrap it. But I agree, it is ok for question description. In my case I need to do something concerning overflow or wrapping.

Comment: if you past some text with multiple lines then it will not work as well.

Answer (score -1):

its posible with wrap="soft,hard, or off

Comment: that will not prevent the line break.