# Linebreak validation on text box

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to add validation to a TextArea which stops a user entering a line-break (basicially stop them pressing 'Enter')?

Comment: No, there's no way you can stop the user from pressing Enter.

Comment: Text boxes don't accept line breaks by default... do you mean a TextArea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651755/disable-linebreaks-in-html-textarea

this is what you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess this helps:

```
<textarea onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) return false;"></textarea>
```