# AngularJS unexpectedly leaves line break in textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When a user presses return after typing in my `textbox` the content should be pushed to some other model and the `textarea` should clear:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul><li ng-repeat="msg in messages">{{msg.body}}</li></ul>
  <textarea ng-model="msg" ng-keydown="addMessage($event)"></textarea>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.messages = [];
  $scope.addMessage = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    $scope.messages.push({body: $scope.msg});
    $scope.msg = "";
  }
}
```

However, `$scope.msg = ""` leaves the line break so the next message starts on the second line of an otherwise empty `textarea`. How can I can I clear it entirely and start the next input on the first line? Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiattp/y8WjA/4/) to demonstrate, and here is a non-angular [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429757/remove-line-break-from-textarea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your event handler is executed(and you clear the textarea), the default event handling mechanism is triggered - which adds the newline from pressing enter. You should prevent the default in your handler(`e.preventDefault()`) : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8WjA/5/)

Edit: It seems like the question was answered in the link you mentioned already.

Comment: Good call, for some reason I thought `return false` would have accomplished that and figured it was a different issue. Thanks!

Comment: `return false` might not accomplish it due to angularjs wrapping the function you provide it in its own event handler(which doesn't `return false` if you do)