# JavaScript - How to remove new line from textarea if no text exists before?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textarea` and I want to remove new lines from it, if the return key is pressed, without writing any text. I tried this, but it did not work:

```
function keypress(id) {
  $("#"+id).keypress(function(event) {
    $("#"+id).val().replace(/\n/g, "");
  });
}
```

Comment: So you need to log the keys pressed and then check for `return` key to be pressed as well?

Comment: So what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Possiible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429757/remove-line-break-from-textarea

Comment: when u press return key it inserts new line and I don't want to submit only new line without any text.

Comment: just want to remove new line when return key pressed without writing any text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function keypress(id) {
    $("#" + id).keyup(function (event) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^\s*(\n)\s*$/, ''))
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wcr3fp23/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Javascript `trim` method.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string.
>   Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space,
>   tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF,
>   CR, etc.).

```
function keypress(id) {
   $("#"+id).keypress(function(event) {
      $("#"+id).val().trim();
   });
}
```