# Deleting the Contents of a Text Area Does Not Delete New Lines

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML/JS I have a script that copies the test from a `textarea` when enter is pressed, then deletes the text. The problem is that the line break from the enter button stays after I delete the text. My code is below.

```js
function Send() {
    let lastText = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
    document.getElementById("sent").innerHTML = lastText;
    document.getElementById("textInput").value = "";
}

function KeyDetection (event) {
    let key = event.key;
    if (key == "Enter") {
        Send()
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea 
    id = "textInput" 
    class = "textInput"
    rows = "1" 
    cols = "50" 
    placeholder = "Write Here"
    onkeydown = "KeyDetection(event)"></textarea>

<p id = "sent"></p>
```

I tried using null and an empty string. I wanted it to delete the line break from pressing enter, but it did not.

Comment: I *think* the problem is that "keydown" fires *before* the value of the input element is updated. After the event handler is finished, the browser completes the user action by adding the key value to the element value.  Probably preventing default action would help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove line break from textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429757/remove-line-break-from-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to prevent the addition of a line break when pressing Enter, you can achieve this by using the `event.preventDefault()` method. This will effectively cancel the default behavior of the Enter keypress event.

```
function KeyDetection(event) {
  let key = event.key;
  if (key == "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    Send();
  }
}
```